# Unit separator in C++

Tags: c++

How could I include a unit separator (value 31 in ascii table) in a string other than using `snprintf()`? I want to do like we normally initialize a string.

eg

```
char[100] a = "abc"
```

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of `char[x]`: `std::string a("abc");`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

31 in dec = 0x1f in hex. Therefore,

```
char x[] = "blah\x1f" "blah";
//              ^^^^ unit separator.
```

The string is split into two to avoid the compiler reading the escape sequence as 0x1fb (it should be read as 0x1f, which is 31 in decimal). Alternatively you could use octal sequence:

```
char x[] = "blah\037blah";
//              ^^^^ unit separator.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to implement it but I think because my string include other int value as well,say "\x1f15". Hence, I think the compiler try to take the 15 as well. It gives the warning of hex sequence out of range. As way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
char str[] = {'a',31,'b','c',0};
```

Comment: You can - but would you really want to?  It might not be too painful for this string, but for anything longer, or doing it more than once ... ouch!